# building application that uses templates client side vs server side

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

Hi I'm building an application that uses templates to create subsites using JSOM. I have one SC and a team site that I have customised. I've saved the team site as a template and then using jsom am able to create replica's of the teamsite.

However I've had a few issues. When I create from the template existing lookups (person field) is blank. I can live with this as I can re-populate manually.
The current issue is that some of the lists in the team site have unique permissions, these are lost whilst using templates. I guess I could run further jsom scripts at the time of provisioning to solve this but I have 4-6 lists.

I'm now thinking this application might be better as a server sided solution, could anyone confirm if this would be a better option. i.e. can I provision subsites and retain unique permisions etc?

Comment: Unfortunately permissions are not preserved in templates. Server side perms are easy to do in PS however if you are going to do that you might as well stick with js.

Comment: If I used a VS solution would I still need to use a template to create subsites ? Is there not another way that the subsite could be provisioned that retains permissions?

Comment: Sure you could create a solution to do it for you but in my opinion it is much easier to do via PowerShell. End result is still the same and I'm sure there are tons of PS examples out there. If you need more detail on how to do it in PS I can post something.